# Windows: Can I change my keyboard keymapping not being an administrator?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout

I don't have admin rights in my work machine. it runs Windows 7. Can I remap the keys in my keyboard? I've just repaired an old Model M keyboard and would like to use the caps lock as the windows key.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This can be done. Follow these steps to do this:

1. Download [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) portable version (believe you cannot install if not admin).
2. Create a scrip file (.ahk) for `AutoHotKey` and add a line as `CapsLock::LWin`
3. Now save the file and run it with `AutoHotKey`

You are done. Now when ever you press `Caps Lock` key, it will work as `Win` key. In script `LWin` is win key at left side of space bar. [More Details](https://autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm).